# rviz crashes on indigo /osx due to serializer implementation

Tags: rviz, ogre, osx, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ogre apparently cannot find a serializer implementation. Are the other platforms using a newer Ogre?
Would it help to rebuild Ogre?

```
  rosrun rviz rviz                                                                                                                                                                      
    [ INFO] [1405425532.925741000]: rviz version 1.11.3
    [ INFO] [1405425532.925794000]: compiled against OGRE version 1.7.4 (Cthugha)
    2014-07-15 13:58:53.145 rviz[67820:d0b] invalid drawable
    [ INFO] [1405425533.162279000]: Stereo is NOT SUPPORTED
    [ INFO] [1405425533.162365000]: OpenGl version: 2.1 (GLSL 1.2).
    2014-07-15 13:58:53.262 rviz[67820:d0b] invalid drawable
    [ WARN] [1405425533.469035000]: OGRE EXCEPTION(7:InternalErrorException): Cannot find serializer implementation for current version [MeshSerializer_v1.8] in MeshSerializer::importMesh at /tmp/ogre-dmWe/ogre_src_v1-7-4/OgreMain/src/OgreMeshSerializer.cpp (line 118)
    libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type Ogre::InternalErrorException: OGRE EXCEPTION(7:InternalErrorException): Cannot find serializer implementation for current version [MeshSerializer_v1.8] in MeshSerializer::importMesh at /tmp/ogre-dmWe/ogre_src_v1-7-4/OgreMain/src/OgreMeshSerializer.cpp (line 118)
    [1]    67820 abort      rosrun rviz rviz
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/186635/rviz-crashes-on-indigo-/osx-due-to-serializer-implementation/) by [J.M.T.](https://answers.ros.org/users/3816/j.m.t./) on ROS Answers with karma: 266 on 2014-07-15

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) on 2014-07-15**:
I can confirm this issue. Ogre needs to be at least versio 1.8, but there are still problems with installing recent versions of ogre on OS X, see: https://github.com/ros-visualization/rviz/issues/782

**Comment by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) on 2014-07-15**:
@William, can hydro rviz be built with ogre1.9? If so, we should find a fix for the 1.9 installation of ogre and then update the homebrew formula to version 1.9.

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2014-07-15**:
Yes it can, you just get a warning about the mesh types being out of date, which is where this change came in for Indigo and using Ogre 1.9 meshes.

**Comment by [LucaGhera](https://answers.ros.org/users/871/lucaghera/) on 2014-09-08**:
@William is there a fix for this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

rviz 1.11.3 is for Indigo, Indigo requires ogre 1.8 or 1.9. You have ogre 1.7 installed and it cannot process the mesh files.

An alternative is to get the 1.7 version of the mesh files for rviz by reverting this commit:

https://github.com/ros-visualization/rviz/commit/1aad3d89feba77d7a356888436ed83bc701a97f6

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2014-09-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [westeast](https://answers.ros.org/users/30354/westeast/) on 2017-06-17**:
I solve this problem by git revert commit_id and then copy the model file .